# How to Access Server After Cisco AnyConnect Connected?

Tags: windows-server-2003, vpn, cisco, connection

I have bought a **VPS with Windows Server 2003** and **Valid Public IP  a.b.c.d**
In this Server I have to Connect to **Another Private Network with Cisco Any Connect**
also I have to RUN a CCProxy (http proxy server for windows ) for Using Cisco Connected Network in My Applications.
**After** connecting to **Cisco VPN in My VPS**, I **Could Not** Access to My **Public IP Anymore**

How Could I Solve This?

Comment: Can you access the private IP?

Comment: No! The Private IP is invalid for my network at home like 172.20.20.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I admit to being initially confused by your question, because this sounds like a nonstandard configuration.  I'd expect you to be installing AnyConnect on your home machine.  (I suspect this is Cisco's assumption as well;  I don't see Server 2003 as [an approved OS for AnyConnect](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/anyconnect-vpn-client/107391-anyconnect-faqs.html).)  Rather than ask you what specific problem you're trying to solve with this configuration, I'm just going to move forward.

It sounds to me--although it's hard to say based on the information you've provided--like your VPN account needs to be set up with [split tunneling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_tunneling).  This would allow the remote server to "talk" to both the private network and the public network at the same time.

[image]

This is supported if you're running new enough versions of ASA and AnyConnect:

- ASA Security Appliance needs to run version 8.x or higher
- Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client needs to be 2.x or higher

Assuming AnyConnect runs fine on server 2003 despite being unsupported, you should be able to set up Split Tunneling on that particular account.  You haven't said whether you control the Cisco equipment in question or not, but, if so, there's a configuration example [here](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/100936-asa8x-split-tunnel-anyconnect-config.html).  Otherwise, you'll have to talk to the person who manages the Cisco equipment.

Comment: Wow! You Are My Hero! Thanks! I will Change my OS to Higher Version like 2008 and I think with your Helpfull answer I will Solve the problem!